# Firebase Analytics: .UserProperty - user_id

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

[По этой ссылке](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.UserProperty?authuser=0) хочу использовать `user_id`

```
public static void sendUserData(Context context, int userId){
    try {
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).setUserProperty("user_id", "" + userId);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**но я не знаю, правильно ли я отправляю id пользователя?** Мне нужно на сайте аналитики увидеть эти `user_id`, но я и не знаю, в какой вкладке это должно быть. Либо я не правильно устанавливаю свойство пользователя?

А этот код рабочий:

```
public static void sendItem(Context context, Product product) {
    if (product != null) {
        try {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("item_id", String.valueOf(product.getId()));
            params.putString("type", String.valueOf(product.getType()));
            params.putString("category_id", String.valueOf(product.getCategoryId()));
            params.putString("name", String.valueOf(product.getName()));
            FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).logEvent("view_item", params);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Так что я уверен, Firebase в проекте правильно настроен и отправляет данные товара в аналитику

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл. Результат работы смог увидеть в Google BigQuery - на сайте гугловской базы данных

В моём случае - **833442** (заношу в лишнее поле id, но всё-таки заносится, хоть и лишнее, так как для тестов вызывал 2 разных метода)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]